# Calculating Inter-Observer Reliability when not all categories are scored

Tags: sas, agreement-statistics

I have two main questions:

**1) Is there a way to calculate IRR when the range of scores differ between observers? If not, how do you get IRR without excluding data?**

I am calculating inter-observer reliability (IRR) for 2 observers who will be collecting data during a study. When I run the IRR in SAS, the Kappa statistics (weighted Kappa and Chance-Corrected AC1) are not computed if there is a missing category for one observer. For example, if observer 1 never used a score of 4, but observer 2 used a score of 4 once.

**2) Is it possible to define the scoring system range in the statistics program?** I.e., the number of categories in the system

Context: the scoring system is a 4-point scale (1, 2, 3, 4) that is standard in my field of research. The difference between scores 1 and 2 is less than the difference between scores 1 and 4. In the population used for our study, scores of 1 and 2 are very common, a score of 3 is less common, and a score of 4 is rare. Calculating an IRR on a scoring system of 1-3 does not take into consideration that there was a possible 4th score category, and this seems important - in my experience, a scoring system with fewer categories generally has higher agreement.

I've tried adding dummy variables (1, 2, 3, 4) for each observer, but if they match between observers then it counts towards better IRR, and if they do not match, then it lowers IRR.

Are these limitations with using SAS? Is there another program I could use?